# Which flash trigger to buy for Canon?

Tags: flash, dslr, wireless-triggers, wireless-flash, canon-6d

There's a ton of options out there. I already bought the Altura trigger set, but I realized it only works when the transmitter/receiver are put side-by-side, very inconsistent results, will only work in Manual mode, no TTL support. After struggling for a long time trying to fix it, talking to Customer care (they sent a replacement, which is not working either), I've realized its just a waste of time trying to make it work.

Current flash kit: Canon 6d2, 2x Altura TTL flashes, 3x Altura transmitters, 4 receivers

1. Can you suggest some options if I'm looking for:

   - Budget option
   - Supports TTL
   - Radio (not Optical)
   - HSS
   - Possible to set/adjust settings/flash power from the camera/transmitter itself
   - If possible, triggers that work with 3rd party flashes (I have Altura flashes already, I'd like to use them at least for sometime rather than buy new flashes)

From my research so far I'm leaning towards Yongnuo or Godox. I'm struggling to understand the differences between all the Yongnuo models (esp. between yn 622c, 622cx, RF-603c,  YN-E3-RT, YN-560TX).

2. In the future, what flashes should I buy with the suggested trigger set?

Comment: Optical and radio are both *wireless*. You need to say *radio* if you don't want wireless that is optical.

Comment: @MichaelC Done. Corrected it.

Comment: Related: [What is the difference between the YN560Tx and the YN-E3-RT?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/93823/1587) and [Universal wireless radio transmitter that can trigger Elinchrom studio strobes, Yongnuo speedlites and Godox flash](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/103607/15871)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both Yongnuo's 622 and RT systems can do TTL and HSS with Canon gear; the 560/60x gear does not do either.

I would (currently) recommend going with Godox over Yongnuo for a few reasons. But this type of flash technology tends to move very quickly. So this answer may become outdated very quickly. Even only two years ago, Yongnuo would have been the answer.

Yongnuo has three separate mostly incompatible triggering systems, and tracking what works with what can be a PITA (see also: [What are the Yongnuo flash naming conventions?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/47702/what-are-the-yongnuo-flash-naming-conventions)). Yongnuo also only supports TTL/HSS for Canon and Nikon (and the for-Canon gear does not work with the for-Nikon gear). And for off-camera lighting, Yongnuo only really makes speedlights.

Godox has [an integrated system](http://flashhavoc.com/godox-flash-system-overview/) where the manual-only gear works with the TTL gear in the same triggering system; all the lights do HSS as off-camera radio slaves; they support TTL/HSS for Canon, Nikon, Sony, Fuji, Olympus/Panasonic, and Pentax; and the TTL lights (aside from the 350 mini speedlights), can autoswitch for any of the supported systems. So, if you switch to or add non-Canon mirrorless gear, or want to share your lights with a different-system shooter, it's possible. All you need is a new trigger with the right pin-out pattern for the new camera's hot shoe. Godox also has X1R-C receivers to include Canon eTTL gear in the Godox system, but the X1R doesn't do the cross-brand TTL switching.

Canon's OEM RT gear is probably the fullest-featured, but the most expensive. But there are also 3rd-party systems that work with Canon's RT gear: Phottix's Laso triggers and the Jinbei/Orlit RT gear. And a lot of radio trigger systems do TTL: Profoto Air, Nissin Air, PocketWizard flex/mini, Phottix Odin II, Cactus V6II, RadioPopper PX, etc. etc.  But Godox and Yongnuo are the lowest-cost ones you're likely to find.

Keep in mind the tradeoff of the low low price tags is a distinct lack of customer support, so whichever retailer you purchase from is going to be key in getting a lemon copy issue resolved.

See also: [What should I look for in a wireless flash trigger for a home studio?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/57653/what-should-i-look-for-in-a-wireless-flash-trigger-for-a-home-studio?rq=1)

Comment: Yongnuo's RT clones are all cross compatible with Canon's RT system (and most other RT clones from other makers).

Comment: @MichaelC, but not Jinbei/Orlit from all reports.

Comment: @inkista Ty. I've been reading about the Godox flashes. Do you know if you can change the slave flash settings from the master flash itself? And the differences between TT350, TT685, V350, V850. From what I read the V's are powered by Li-ion and TT's by AA batteries. Anything else I'm missing?

Comment: @deppfx, if you have new questions, might be best to post them as new questions. :)  Also, the flashhavoc overview I linked to under "integrated system" pretty much lays out the entire system.

Answer (score 1):

Partial answer:

- The Yongnuo YN-E3-RT is a clone of the Canon ST-E3-RT radio transmitter and supports E-TTL with Canon RT flashes (and clones of Canon RT flashes). I use one with a an EOS 70D and Canon 430-EX III-RT. I intend to complement my 430-EX III-RT with other Canon-compatible flashes.
- The YN-622C-TX does E-TLL (could not be compatible with some Canon models) and needs Yongnuo YN-622C receivers to control the flashes.
- The YN-560TX only works with Yongnuo flashes and only supports manual mode (from Amazon user comments)(but you can control the flash power from it).
- The RF-603C is a fairly basic thing (only does radio triggering) that works with other RF-603C (you decide which one if the emitter).

Comment: A YN-560TX transmitter with an RF605 receiver will work in manual mode with any flash. You won't be able to remotely control power or zoom, but you can switch groups on or off remotely.